# Como colocar imagens randômicas a cada acesso?

Tags: php

No Slide abaixo, é possível fazer com que toda vez que entrar no site ser exibido um slide diferente e não segui a sequencia?

Se esse slide fosse html+css3 seria possível também, sem a presença do javascript?

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html

E como posso fazer com que essas imagem sejam trazidas do banco de dados? lembrando que o slide em html5.

Comment: por favor poste um pouco do código que você utilizou, se tratando de desenvolvimento "quase" tudo é possível, só precisa saber como você está fazendo e implementar isso.

Answer (score 1):

> Se esse slide fosse html+css3 seria possível também, sem a presença do javascript?

Não, você tem botões com ações isso o css3 não faz...

> E como posso fazer com que essas imagem sejam trazidas do banco de dados?

Seguindo o exemplo da [conexão de dados](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.query.php)

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
<?php
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo '<li><img src="'.$row['name'].'" /></li>';
}
?>
  </ul>
</div>
```